# How to create a constructor/builder for nested Java classes?

Tags: java, constructor, nested, builder

Let's say I want to mock a class with the following structure, for testing purposes:

```
@Data
public class Street() {

    private House house;

    @Data
    static class House {
        private List<Room> rooms;
    }

    @Data
    static class Room {
        private Door door;
    }

    @Data
    static class Door {
        private String material;
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to concisely create a `Street` object, containing a `House` that has a `Room` with a wooden door?

I was thinking of adding a Lombok `@Builder` annotation to the `Street` class, but discovered I would also need builders for each of the nested classes, and was wondering if there would be a cleaner way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use @SuperBuilder from lombok project

Assume you have :

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Parent {
    private final String parentName;
    private final int parentAge;
}

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {
    private final String childName;
    private final int childAge;
}

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Student extends Child {
    private final String schoolName;
}
```

Then you can create a new Student like this :

```
Student student = Student.builder()
  .parentName("Andrea")
  .parentAge(38)
  .childName("Emma")
  .childAge(6)
  .schoolName("Baeldung High School")
  .build();
```

Reference : https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance#lombok-builder-and-inheritance-1

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is this:

```
public class Street {
    
    private House house;
    private Room room;
    private Door door;
    

    public class House{
        //build class House
    }
    
    public class Room{
        //build class Room
    }

    public class Door{
        //build class Door
    }
    
    public Street(House house, Room room, Door door) {
        this.house = new House();
        this.room = new Room();
        this.door = new Door(); 
    }
    
}
```

and then you can work inside the Street class with the objects you have to access methods of the other little classed nested into Street